# weighted.mean inside aggregate across 2 vectors in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, weighted-average

I have a dataframe with vectors `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `Period`, and `ID`. I would like to calculate the positional centroid for each period (*n* = 2), weighted by the number of observations for each unique ID, so that IDs with fewer observations receive higher weights than those with more observations.

My dataframe is 300,000 obs but looks something like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(Latitude = c(35.8, 35.85, 36.7, 35.2, 36.1, 35.859, 36.0, 37.0, 35.1, 35.2),
                  Longitude = c(-89.4, -89.5, -89.4, -89.8, -90, -89.63, -89.7, -89, -88.9, -89),
                  Period = c(early, early, early, early, early, late, late, late, late, late),
                  ID = c(A, A, A, B, C, C, C, D, E, E))
```

I can easily calculate the mean between early and late periods using aggregate... `centroid <- aggregate(cbind(Longitude, Latitude) ~ Period, dat, mean)` but is there a way to calculate the centroid for each period weighted by the number of observations for each ID so that those with more observations do not bias the mean? And, if possible, is there an elegant way of doing this inside the `aggregate` function or a `dplyr` solution also would be helpful.

Any assistance would be much appreciated. Best,

Nick

Comment: How does your expected output based on your data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate your own weights, based on the group `Period` and `ID` so that each `ID` has the same influence on the centeriods by `Period` then we just need to divide 1 through the number of observations in each `Perdiod` `ID` group. Below is the code using `weighted.mean` in `dplyr::across`.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(Period, ID) %>% 
  mutate(weight = 1/n()) %>% 
  group_by(Period) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(Longitude, Latitude),
                   ~ weighted.mean(.x, w = weight)))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   Period Longitude Latitude
#>   <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 early      -89.7     35.8
#> 2 late       -89.2     36.0

# data
dat <- data.frame(Latitude = c(35.8, 35.85, 36.7, 35.2, 36.1, 35.859, 36.0, 37.0, 35.1, 35.2),
                  Longitude = c(-89.4, -89.5, -89.4, -89.8, -90, -89.63, -89.7, -89, -88.9, -89),
                  Period = rep(c("early", "late"), each = 5),
                  ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", "E"))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You could calculate the first two in one statement: `add_count(ID, Period)` and than use `1/n` as weight for `weighted.mean`. This saves one line. ;-)

Comment: @MartinGal: Thats a nice trick to save a line! I leave the code above as is, since weights are often expressed in values between 0 and 1, but it is good to know that it can be shortened.